# How do I move an item to an empty list between groups using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have multiple sortable list. It can able to do **Reorder the groups**, 
**Reorder the items within the groups**,**Move the items between the groups**.

But It cannot move the item from one group to other empty group.

[image]

Here I need to move any item from Group2 to Group1

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fc9a27v/), I tried the below code

```
$(function(){
 $('#groupsList').sortable();
  $('.itemsList').sortable({
    connectWith: ['.group','.itemsList']
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most likely because the other list has no visible height when it's empty, so you can't trigger the 'drop' on it. Try setting a `min-height` on the `ul` in CSS. Without seeing the actual HTML this is just a guess, though

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Please check fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/8fc9a27v/

Comment: Thanks for the example. The issue is as I suspected; due to no height taken up by the target element. I added an answer for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because the `.itemsList` elements have no height when they are empty. As such it's not possible for a drag related event to be triggered on them.

One solution would be to set `min-height` on the elements so that they always take up space in the DOM, even when empty. Try this:

```
.itemsList {
  min-height: 10px;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#groupsList').sortable();
  $('.itemsList').sortable({
    connectWith: ['.group', '.itemsList']
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  background-color: #ffcb05;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: move;
}

div:not(.container) {
  background-color: #00274c;
  min-height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}

.group {
  min-height: 50px;
}

.itemsList {
  min-height: 10px;
  border: 1px dotted #bd9700;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" /><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul id="groupsList" class="groupsList">
  <li id="group1" class="group">Group 1
    <ul id="groupItems1" class="itemsList">

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="group2" class="group">Group 2
    <ul id="groupItems2" class="itemsList">
      <li id="item1-1" class="item">Item 1.1</li>
      <li id="item1-2" class="item">Item 1.2</li>
      <li id="item2-1" class="item">Item 2.1</li>
      <li id="item2-2" class="item">Item 2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="group3" class="group">Group 3
    <ul id="groupItems3" class="itemsList">
      <li id="item3-1" class="item">Item 3.1</li>
      <li id="item3-2" class="item">Item 3.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note that I put a border around the `.itemsList` in the example above to make it clearer that the minimum height setting is in place.